Type of model to measure spread between two assets
I am analyzing the price between two assets and the relationship between various features that impact them.
The vast majority of the time, over $90%$, the assets are equally valued, thus the spread is $0$. However, when the conditions are right, certain features are very high or very low, the the spread increases.
What type of modeling can help either predict the spread or classify if a spread exists?
I am new to data science/machine learning. I have tried a simple linear regression model but the performance is incredibly poor. My guess is because the vast majority of the time there is no spread so the LSRL will just be a flat line going through $0$.
Would also like some tips or recommended resources if anyone has any, thank you!

Logistic regression with binary response spread (yes or no) comes to mind. If you want to use the actual spread amount, as well as the cases of zero spread, Tobit regression comes to mind.

You actually answered your own question when you said 'classify'! You will want to use a logistic regression algorithm where the response variable (y) is either 0 (no) or 1 (yes). There are a treasure trove of resources for logistic regression on the internet.


Do you really just want to predict if there is or is not a spread without regard for what the spread is? Why? $//$ 2. Many models in finance have limited predictive ability. Your poor performance should not be surprising, as many models are, at best, only slightly better than simple benchmarks like the historical average. $//$ 3. You seem to have features that might be predictive, however, when you mention that, "when the conditions are right, certain features are very high or very low, the the spread increases." How are you determining this? $//$ 4. What linear regression did you do?


Graph your relationships.  Graph the price difference as a function of each independent variable.  You may find a nonlinear effect, given that you've said "when the conditions are right, certain features are very high or very low, the the spread increases."  You may even find a threshold (a.k.a. stair-step) effect.  In either case, to capture the relationship you would need to build in more than standard linear-regression effects.  This approach should be more sensitive than logistic regression, which would need to bin the price difference into two categories, losing information in the process.  However, given the prevalence of zeros, you may want to look into zero-inflated models.
